# Conditional probability and independence using Bayes' rule and binomial expansion

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, factorial, binomial-theorem, bayes-theorem

I would like to start the question by adding some context.

Tom is a night owl and is very hungry at night.
On day , he eats at home with probability 1− (0<<1); or, with probability , he goes out and goes the -th restaurant in his city. At any restaurant that he goes to, either:

(i) the restaurant is open with probability  (where 0<<1). In that case, Tom orders some food for take-away;

(ii) the restaurant is closed so Tom returns home and has sleep for dinner because he is sad.

We assume that the collection of all events of the form {Tom stays home on day } and {The -th restaurant is open on day }, for =1,2,…, are (mutually) independent.

The probability that Tom orders some food for take-away on the first day is $p*q$. So simple?

Furthermore, fixing some integers  and , with ≥1 and 0≤≤.

The probability that he ordered food for take-away exactly  times on the first  days is

$${n \choose k}q^k(1-q)^{n-k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}*q^k(1-q)^{n-k}$$

This doesn't seem right to me. What about $p$? Tom only orders food if he goes out, which is probability of $p$.

The conditional probability of Tom staying home on day 1, given that he did not order food on that day is

$$\frac{1-p}{p*(1-q)}$$

Where $p*(1-q)$ is basically the he went out and the restaurant was closed. But he can also decide to stay home with probability of $1-p$ which means he doesn't order food.

My actual question is,

Within the first week (7 days), what is the probability that there were no days in which Tom went out but did not order food from a restaurant?

That conjunctive "but" in the question confuses me. If he doesn't go out in 7 days in a row, I would say $(1-p)^7$

I don't know, this all feels wrong. Please help me and feel free to correct my reasoning.

---

EDIT

Tom ordering food for take-away exactly  times on the first  days should be

$${n \choose k}(pq)^k(1-pq)^{n-k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}*(pq)^k(1-pq)^{n-k}$$

Comment: Your "What about p?" is a good question.  I would have replaced all the $q$s in the previous expression with $pq$.

Comment: Then for your "actual question", I would use a similar expression but this time with $p(1-q)$ and let $k=0$ and $n=7$

Comment: The "but" in the given context means that  on all days that he went out he *did* order food.

Comment: Yes, you're completely right @Henry . $p$ Should actually be $pq$ in the formula. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the insight regarding my "actual question". Substituting in $p(1-q)$ leads to $${7 \choose 0}(p(1-q))^0(1-p(1-q))^{7-0}=(1-p(1-q))^{7}=(1-p+pq)^7$$ Does this seem correct to you? @Henry

Comment: I figured there might be another mistake regarding the conditional probability. Being $∗(1−)$ and $1-$ both probabilities of interest, then instead of $$\frac{1-p}{p(1-q)}$$ it actually should be $$\frac{1-p}{p(1-q)+(1-p)}=\frac{1-p}{1-pq}$$ because either Tom goes out and the restaurant was closed with probability of $∗(1−)$ meaning that he didn't order food and Tom stays at home with probability of $1-$ which also means that he didn't order food. Do you mind pointing out if this reasoning is correct or should I post a separate question on that matter? Thanks in advance @Henry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct interpretation is

- Tom goes out
- Tom doesn't order food

Mathematically, that's all we need to know. Hence

$${7 \choose 0}((1−))^0(1-(1−))^{7-0}=(1-(1−))^{7}=(1−+)^{7}$$

Where $(1−)$ denotes the probability for the interpretation above.

Comment: You are forgetting the first part of the "actual question" which states "*there were  no days on which Tom went out* **but** did not order food from a restaurant." The ambiguity was arising from the BUT, and in English Language SE, the lone view in the comment agrees with my interpretation. I have nothing more to say.

Comment: Again, reinforcing the fact @Henry pointed that out and I agreed with him. I am proficient in English First Language (C1) and still found the formulation of the "actual question" confusing. Nevertheless, I submitted this answer and it turns out that it was correct. And probably there are many more mathematicians who would agree with me.

Comment: You were confused by BUT, weren't you ? Whatever it means, the wording is very clumsy and vague. But if "the book" okays your interpretation, what can I say ?  Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

To address your "actual question" , I interpret the wording to mean that on each day that he goes out, the restaurant is open so he can and does order food. [= On no day that he goes out does he not order food]

P(Tom goes out on $k$ days in  a week) = $\binom7{k}p^k(1-p)^{7-k}$

P(restaurant open on each of these particular $k$ days) $= q^k$

Thus indicated $Pr = \binom7{k}(pq)^k(1-p)^{7-k}$

Comment: Shouldn't $k=0$ if Tom "did not order food from a restaurant"? Please correct me if I'm wrong, however, I am with @Henry on this one. Given $k=0$ then $$Pr = \binom7{0}(pq)^0(1-p)^{7-0}=(1-p)^7$$ That is exactly what I posted in my question, which I'm still doubting on it. It seems okay, but I feel like $(1-p)^7$ is missing something. Also, why do you say " days" instead of " days" ? This confuses me a little, maybe you could clarify on that matter.

Comment: Maybe if you change the structure of the query from " there were no days in which Tom went out but did not order food" to *Tom went out... there were no days...did not order food* it will be clearer. I am afraid the part $\binom70p^0...$ in your attempt means Tom didn't go out at all that week !

Comment: Yeah, I have to admit that the formulation of the query is painful. It's what the problem said (I didn't edit it) and the "but" is still confusing to me. Based on your comment, isn't "there were no days in which Tom went out" the same as "Tom didn't go out at all that week"? Hence $\binom7{0}(pq)^0$? I interpret it as 0 days he went out means he stayed home.

Comment: If he doesn't go out, it is *certain* he doesn't order food, so that just can't be a correct interpretation. Also, btw, $n =7$ in the week, and $k$ is the number of days he goes out, there's no confusion there. Anyway, very late here, good night.

Comment: Yes, you are right when it comes to "if he doesn't go out, it is certain he doesn't order food". The way I see the query, Tom goes out and Tom doesn't order food as in $p(1-q)$. I will let you know along the next days if your answer was correct. Thanks for your help though @trueblueanil Good night

Comment: Have a look at the comment section here. It agrees with my interpretation.  https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/585743/correct-interpretation-of-a-rather-convoluted-sentence

Comment: It's wrong because you used "$k$ days" as in "  is the number of days he goes out" or " days in a week". The context explicitly states that it's "the probability that he ordered food for take-away exactly  times on the first  days". So $k$ is the number of times the restaurant was open and he ordered food, for which the question asks Tom "did not order food from a restaurant" @trueblueanil

Comment: I took them as two separate questions,  If it confuses you, just change the answer to $Pr = \binom7{j}(pq)^j(1-p)^{7-j},$ where $j$ is the number of days he went out in those $7$ days

Comment: That's exactly what's wrong. You cannot apply $k$ or in that sense "$j$ is the number of days he went out in those 7 days" because we already know that he went out all of the days BUT did not order food. More precisely, given the context "he ordered food for take-away exactly  times on the first  days", as we already know from the question that translates into Tom "ordered food for take-away exactly 0 times on the first 7 days". And from there on solve the problem with the binomial expansion. Check my answer @trueblueanil

Comment: I have put a comment there