# Conditional probability using Bayes' rule

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

This question is based on a previous question that I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4398808/conditional-probability-and-independence-using-bayes-rule-and-binomial-expansio). Same context as before:

Tom is a night owl and is very hungry at night. On day , he eats at home with probability 1− (0<<1); or, with probability , he goes out and goes the -th restaurant in his city. At any restaurant that he goes to, either:

(i) the restaurant is open with probability  (where 0<<1). In that case, Tom orders some food for take-away;

(ii) the restaurant is closed so Tom returns home and has sleep for dinner because he is sad.

We assume that the collection of all events of the form {Tom stays home on day } and {The -th restaurant is open on day }, for =1,2,…, are (mutually) independent.

I stated that the conditional probability of Tom staying home on day 1, given that he did not order food on that day is

$$\frac{1-p}{p(1-q)}$$

However, I think that previous probability is wrong, and that instead it should actually be

$$\frac{1-p}{p\left(1-q\right)+(1-p)}=\frac{1-p}{1-pq}$$

Because either Tom goes out and the restaurant was closed with probability of (1−) meaning that he didn't order food and Tom stays at home with probability of 1− which also means that he didn't order food.

Could someone please tell me which one of these two conditional probabilities is correct?

I want to believe it's the second one. Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: The second one is correct and follows from Bayes' rule. The first one is not even a valid probability for all $p,q$; just think what happens for $p\approx 0$.

Comment: Of course you cannot divide by 0 :) @Golden_Ratio

Comment: Not only that, the probability will exceed 1 even for $p>0$ small enough

Comment: The denominator must always represent more events than the numerator. This is because conditional probability represents a subset of the total events.

Comment: Thanks for the remark @TobyMak

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever confused re Bayes' Rule, it is a good idea to draw a contingency diagram

$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$ Went Out $\;\;\;\;$ Stayed home

Ordered food $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$pq $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; 0$

Didn't order food $\;\;\;$p(1-q) $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$  (1-p)

You should be able to clearly see that your second formula is correct